# exit from bash script that uses $()

Tags: bash

I was under impression that `exit` would terminate the current bash script no matter what, and had the following error handler at the top of my script:

```
function err {
    printf "\e[31m$1\e[0m\n" 1>&2
    exit 1
}
```

It worked like a charm for most cases until this line:

```
item=$(myfunc $1)
```

Normally, that line works fine, with the STDOUT of myfunc dumped into `$item`, as intended. The problem arises when `myfunc` throws an error, via the `err` function seen above. The `$()` ends up swallowing the non-zero return and guarding the exit from exiting the script itself. If I understand correctly, the problem is that `$()` actually spawns a new subshell (just like the deprecated backticks), but I know of no other way to capture the output of a function into a variable in bash that allows the `exit` to work.

I tried using `set -e` as well, and had no luck with that either. Can someone suggest how to build my error handler so that it exits the script even in these cases?

Comment: The `$()` ends up swallowing everything because the *command-substitution* takes pace in a *subshell*. What is the bash rule about subshells? *Nothing done in a subshell can effect the parent process...* Yes, you can get the exit status back (`$?`), but you can't do anything else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can test the result of the assignment:

```
if item=$(myfunc "$1")
then : Function worked
else : Function failed
fi
```

This tests the exit status of the command run in the sub-shell that the `$(…)` uses.

---

Without actually using functions, you can experiment with:

```
$ if item=$(echo Hi; exit 1); then echo "$item - OK"; else echo "$item - OH"; fi
Hi - OH
$ if item=$(echo Hi; exit 0); then echo "$item - OK"; else echo "$item - OH"; fi
Hi - OK
$
```

Or, if functions are deemed crucial, then:

```
$ err() { exit $1; }
$ myfunc() { echo Mine; err $1; }
$ if item=$(myfunc 1); then echo "$item - OK"; else echo "$item - OH"; fi
Mine - OH
$ if item=$(myfunc 0); then echo "$item - OK"; else echo "$item - OH"; fi
Mine - OK
$
```

Tested using Bash 3.2.57 on Mac OS X 10.11 El Capitan.

Comment: Hmm, somehow it still seems to always be going into the `worked` case for me no matter what. And probably for the same reason `$?` that David suggested also always stays 0. It looks like it's the assignment that's eating the exit flag.

Comment: This works for me.  +1.   I tested it with `a=$(false); echo code=$?` and `a=$(true); echo code=$?`.  @Alexander, if it doesn't work for you, make sure that `myfunc` (which you haven't shown us) is properly setting exit codes.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: it's one way of getting the functions undefined when you no longer want to use them.  :)  (The other, or at least another, way to undefine them is `unset -f err myfunc` as a command.)

Comment: The reason I haven't shown myfunc is that it's rather and didn't seem relevant. After more playing and reducing, it seems like `$?` was getting reset due to `local` declaration and assignment on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

for what it's worth you also *can't use bash short circuit evaluation* to test the exit status of the function. It tests the assignment to the variable instead.

eg.
while

```
[[ $(myfunc "$1") ]] && echo success || echo failure
```

or

```
[[ myfunc "$1" ]] && echo success || echo failure
```

are fairly common and might do what's expected,

```
[[ item=$(myfunc "$1") ]] && echo success || echo failure
```

Always returns success even if myfunc returns non zero. You have to use if then else to test the exit status.