# BASH - 'exit 1' failed in loop inside another loop

Tags: bash

The following code doesn't exit at the first `exit 1` from the call of `error_exit`. What am I missing?

```bash
#!/bin/bash

THIS_DIR="$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd)"
JINJANG_DIR="$(cd "$THIS_DIR/../.." && pwd)"
DATAS_DIR="$THIS_DIR/datas"

error_exit() {
    echo ""
    echo "ERROR - Following command opens the file that has raised an error."
    echo ""
    echo "  > open \"$1\""
    exit 1
}


cd "$DATAS_DIR"

find . -name 'datas.*'  -type f | sort  | while read -r datafile
do
    localdir="$(dirname $datafile)"
    
    echo "    * Testing ''$localdir''."
    
    filename=$(basename "$datafile")
    ext=${filename##*.}
    
    if [ "$ext" == "py" ]
    then
        unsafe="-u"
    else
        unsafe=""
    fi
    
    datas="$DATAS_DIR/$datafile"

    find . -name 'template.*'  -type f | sort  | while read -r template
    do
        filename=$(basename "$template")
        ext=${filename##*.}

        template="$DATAS_DIR/$template"
        outputfound="$DATAS_DIR/$localdir/output_found.$ext"
        
        cd "$JINJANG_DIR"
        python -m src $UNSAFE "$DATA" "$TEMPLATE" "$OUTPUTFOUND"  || error_exit "$localdir"
    done

    cd "$DATAS_DIR"
done
```

Here is the output I obtain.

```
ERROR - Following command opens the file that has raised an error.

  > open "./html/no-param-1"
    * Testing ''./html/no-param-2''.

ERROR - Following command opens the file that has raised an error.

  > open "./html/no-param-2"
    * Testing ''./latex/no-param-1''.

ERROR - Following command opens the file that has raised an error.

  > open "./latex/no-param-1"
    * Testing ''./latex/no-param-2''.

ERROR - Following command opens the file that has raised an error.
```

Comment: Put a valid [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) and paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Exit bash script within while loop"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43483661/exit-bash-script-within-while-loop). Also somewhat related: ["exit from bash script that uses $()"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32961467/exit-from-bash-script-that-uses).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my `bash` environment invoking `exit` in a subprocess does not abort the parent process, eg:

```
$ echo "1 2 3" | exit                   # does not exit my console but instead ...
$                                       # presents me with the command prompt
```

In your case you have the pipeline: `find | sort | while`, so the `python || error_exit` is being called within a subprocess which in turn means the `exit 1` will apply to the subprocess but not the (parent) script.

One solution that insures the (inner) `while` (and thus the `exit  1`) is not run in a subprocess:

```
while read -r template
do
    ... snip ...
    python ... || error_exit
    ... snip ...
done < <(find . -name 'template.*'  -type f | sort)
```

**NOTES:**

- I'd recommend getting used to this structure as it also addresses another common issue ...
- values assigned to variables in a subprocess are not passed 'up' to the parent process
- subprocess behavior may differ in other shells

Of course, this same issue applies to the parent/outer `while` loop so, if the objective is for the `exit 1` to apply to the entire script then this same structure will need to be implemented for the parent/outer `find | sort | while`, too:

```
while read -r datafile
do
    ... snip ...

    while read -r template
    do
        ... snip ...

        python ... || error_exit

    done < <(find . -name 'template.*'  -type f | sort)

    cd "$DATAS_DIR"
done < <(find . -name 'datas.*'  -type f | sort)
```

---

Additional note copied from [GordonDavisson's edit of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74977217):

> Note that the `<( )` construct ("process substitution") is not
> available in all shells, or even in bash when it's in sh-compatibility
> mode (i.e. when it's invoked as `sh` or `/bin/sh`). So be sure to use
> an explicit bash shebang (like `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`)
> in your script, and don't override it by running the script with the
> `sh` command.

Comment: I proposed ["Exit bash script within while loop"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43483661/exit-bash-script-within-while-loop) as a duplicate, but I think this is a better solution than the one there (though not as portable). Could you also add it as an answer there? (Oh, and I'd recommend adding a note that this only when bash is run *as bash* -- if you invoke it as `sh` or `/bin/sh`, process substitution is disabled.)

Comment: @GordonDavisson The answer in this post uses another simple technic. No?

Comment: Yep, just `|| exit 1` after the loop to propagate the error (which works fine for this specific issue, but doesn't help with the other things you mentioned).

Comment: @GordonDavisson Please read my question again. I had only one problem which was solved by this answer.